# command line: enumerate all "run" registry keys subkeys + data

Tags: for-loop, cmd, registry

I would like to create a cmd script that enumerates 
HKEY_USERS*\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
with all its subkeys.

this is what I have so far but it is not working.. the variable is not set?

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR /F "usebackq " %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKU`) DO (
    set "datareg=%%A\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    @echo %datareg%  >> "%userprofile%\desktop\runregistery.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want in a single line without the use of `set` followed by `echo`.

---

To export a list of keys for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` you can use the following batch file.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq skip=2" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`)  do echo %%a>> "%userprofile%\desktop\runregistery.txt"
```

example output:

```
f.lux
PureText
EPSON
WinPatrol
```

---

If you want key and values for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, then use `reg export`:

```
reg export HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run > reg.out
```

example output:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"f.lux"="\"C:\\Users\\DavidPostill\\AppData\\Local\\FluxSoftware\\Flux\\flux.exe\" /noshow"
"PureText"="\"C:\\apps\\PureText\\PureText.exe\""
"EPSON Stylus Photo RX560 Series"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\spool\\DRIVERS\\x64\\3\\E_IATIBPE.EXE /FU \"C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\E_S8843.tmp\" /EF \"HKCU\""
"WinPatrol"="C:\\apps\\WinPatrol\\winpatrol.exe -expressboot"
```

---

To export a list keys for `HKEY_USERS` you can use the following batch file.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_USERS`)  do (
   set _user=%%a
   for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`reg query !_user!\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 2^> nul`) do (
     echo %%b>> "%userprofile%\desktop\runregistery.txt"
   )
)
```

example output:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Sidebar
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Sidebar
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1699878757-1063190524-3119395976-1000\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
f.lux
PureText
EPSON
WinPatrol
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is that you only export HKCU, I want to export all users ==> HKU, but you never know upfront what the key after the HKU is...

Comment: David, I don't see any updated differences?  Shouldn't I Loop to get the S-id's first and use that s-id in the reg export?

Comment: Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)